# (Swift) detect color and click it

Tags: swift, colors

I'm working on this little Mac App using Swift. When the app detects a certain color, it should simulate a click on it.

I'm using a NSTimer that calls the function "searchForColor()" every second; and when the function detects the color within the app, it clicks it.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: How do you detect the color ? If you detect the coordinate of the pixel which  is in the color you are looking for you could display a popup at the coordinate.

Comment: Hi Manalalz. Sorry if I wasn't specific enough. My app cannot detect the color yet; that's what I'm hoping to accomplish here.

Comment: Are you looking for RGB value or only something more general like purple or blue ?

Comment: Just an RGB value :-)

Comment: So you could look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722627/color-detection-at-a-distance-swift) and maybe parse all of the pixel and compare the value return by the current pixel and yourValue.

Comment: `When the app detects a certain color` What does that mean? Explain this process with details. Does it involve images, how would it work?